# Criação de JSON em java

Tags: java

preciso converter uma classe java para um JSON com objetivo de enviar via post a uma API.

O problema é que cada atributo precisa ser um objeto no json.

Exemplo:
Minha classe

```
public class Parceiro {

String CODPARC;

String nomeParceiro;

public String getCODPARC() {
    return CODPARC;
}

public void setCODPARC(String cODPARC) {
    CODPARC = cODPARC;
}

public String getNomeParceiro() {
    return nomeParceiro;
}

public void setNomeParceiro(String nomeParceiro) {
    this.nomeParceiro = nomeParceiro;
}
}
```

Convertendo para JSON no main:

```
Parceiro par = new Parceiro();
  par.setCODPARC("123");
  
  String jsonString = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(par);

  System.out.println(jsonString);
```

Resultado:
`{"nomeParceiro":null,"codparc":"123"}`

Mas o problema é que preciso converter que fique assim:

`{ "CODPARC":{ "$": "123" }, "NOMEPARC": { "$": "JOAO" }  }`

Existe alguma anotação no java ou jeito pratico desta construção? são cerca de 40 atributos que precisa contender no json.

Comment: Eu não sou proficiente em Java mas olhando por cima parece que um caminho pode ser encontrado aqui https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization

Comment: O que tu precisa fazer é criar uma classe que represente o teu ```CODPARC``` e outra classe que represente o teu ```NOMEPARC``` e devolver ambas numa terceira classe que represente JSON que tu precisa para o POST (não sei qual é o contexto do negócio mas eu iria por esse caminho). Dentro das respectivas classes, tu cria os atributos que tu precisa como, por exemplo o código do parceiro e nome do parceiro. Porém, para representar o ```$``` não sei até que ponto seria boa prática colocar isso dentro de uma anotação ```@value```.